# Zoom in Zoom out loop on action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this code for my effect to zoom in and zoom out in certains buttons

```
canada.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, canadaover);

function canadaover(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay("canadaS");
    trace("in");
}

canada.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, canadaout);

function canadaout(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     gotoAndPlay("canadaF");
     trace("out");
}

canada.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickcanada);

function clickcanada(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse clicked");
}
```

the problem is when u reach certain corner of the button it kinda gets into a loop, any ideas how can i fix this?

here its the link of the swf i'm trying to do:

http://viajescupatitzio.com/america%20map.swf

Comment: you can create hitArea for every button.

Comment: Oh right! that's a great idea thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your buttons are MovieClips you can add inside a layer with a mask (for example rectangle) on top. Mask width and height should be your mouseover region and give it alpha = 0. It will be invisible, but it will work with MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT Events.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your buttons into a different hierarchy level than the graphics you are changing - even if the buttons disappear, or are covered with graphics for just a very short moment, both mouseOver and mouseOut events will be fired (the mouse *has* left and reentered the button) - and that probably causes your "loop".

It is generally a good idea to have animations and graphical objects within nested MovieClips, and place control elements on a higher level of the display list - that way you can make sure the elements don't overlap and/or interfere.